# Is is possible for the user to find out the actual redirected path?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using .htaccess for URL redirection as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^x.php$ /y.php
```

Can the user know some how (even using some advanced tools) that the page was actually served from y.php instead of x.php?

Thanks

Comment: No that's not possible.